# What is the C# equivalent of this VB.NET code: DataTable.GetChanges(Not DataRowState.Deleted)

Tags: c#, vb.net

In VB.NET:

```
DataTable.GetChanges(Not DataRowState.Deleted)
```

What is the equivalent in C#?

Comment: Re you sure this even compiles and works in VB? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I did not try compiling in VB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `Not` there means "bitwise complement"...

```
DataTable.GetChanges(~DataRowState.Deleted)
```

Comment: @MarcGravell any reason for it to Not be !?

Comment: @msarchet because `DataRowState` is an enum, and you can't take the boolean `!` on an enum

Comment: I didn't try but MSDN says "1 of the DataRow states".

Comment: What means "bitwise complement"?  I wants to get all rows except those deleted rows.

Comment: Or I have to do this. DataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added | DataRowState.Modified | DataRowState.Unchanged) ?

Comment: @pengruijun - you can of course build them up forwards with |, but the equivalent to the code in the question is as per the answer here

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable.GetChanges(~DataRowState.Deleted);`

Comment: "Error 1 Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'System.Data.DataRowState'"

Comment: @MarcGravell yea I see that now